# Semantically searching in CSS files

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Imagine I have a huge CSS file with e.g. more than 40000 lines, like https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.css

I want to explore this file and for example search for class definitions containing "hidden" in their name. How can this be done? The word "hidden" can also appear in the definition of the class, so a normal text search is not sufficient. So I am looking for a tool which is able to interpret the CSS file and then allows me to semantically search in it, understanding the difference between "hidden" in a class name and "hidden" in a class definition.

Any tips on this? Thanks!

Update: I am using Visual Studio Code, if there is a matching extension for it, that would be great. A separate tool would also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure which text editor/IDE you are using but most IDE’s allow you to search for classes by name, in which case you could just use “hidden” as the input. In IntelliJ, the command for this is Ctrl+N. You’ll have to check your editor or IDE for the shortcut but a simple Google search should give you the answer.

Comment: You also create a python script to scrape through each line in the file and retrieve the class name if the line contains a “{“ and the word “hidden” (e.g. all class definitions will have “{“ follow the name)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code. Thanks, will have a look at IntelliJ, still wondering if there are "smaller" tools for that or an extension for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Here is another post about that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104951/sublime-text-find-all-instances-of-an-html-class-name-project-wide. Also you might be able to use GREP .

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf I believe if you try CTRL+SHIFT+F and set the search scope to Entire Solution that should work. Not sure if there is a dedicated tool for the process, I can write a script in python to do this if needed

Comment: @JohnCook I tested it, using strg+N I only have matches on the symbols tab, but that finds all matches for the string, no matter what's the context of "hidden"